# How do you add objects to a new vector class in C++?

Tags: c++, class, oop, vector

My goal is to add objects from a class to a new class where they will be stored in a vector, which I will use later to add/delete/display elements.
The vector will act as a database.

In the vector class, I am unsure if I am able to return the inputDB from object class.
Any help will be appreciated. It doesn't necessarily have to be done the way I have wrote it.

**Header file for Object**

```
#ifndef OBJECT_H
#define OBJECT_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

Class Object
{
friend std::istream& inputDB(std::istream&, Object&)

private:
std::string Name

public:
Object(std::string name); //constructor

const std::string& getName() const {return this -> Name;};
}

std::istream &inputDB(std::istream&, Object&)

#endif // OBJECT_H
```

**Source file for Object**

```
#include "OBJECT.H"

Object::Object(std::string name){Name { name }} {};

std::istream &inputDB (std::string istream& is, Object& x)
{
std::cout << "Enter name: ";
is >> x.Object
return is;
}
```

**New vector class header**

```
#ifndef VECTOR_H
#define VECTOR_H

#include <Object.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>



Class VectorDB
{
private:
std::vector<Object> DB;

public:
Database();
void inputDB(std::istream&)
}

#endif // VECTOR_H
```

**Source file for Vector**

```
#include "VECTOR.h"

VectorDB::VectorDB()
{}

void inputDB(std::istream& ist)
{}
```

Comment: `void inputDB(std::istream& ist) {}` does not define function `inputDB` inside class `VectorDB` - it defines a global function called `inputDB`

Comment: most of this is pure fantasy code. I'd start with valid C++ code, unlike what is posted in this question, and carefully consider the *overall* problem you're trying to solve, at *least* as much as trying to fix what you've tunneled into as your solution to that problem (aka, an XY probelm).

Comment: _"In the vector class, I am unsure if I am able to return the inputDB from object class."_ - I'm not sure, I can follow. You mean wether you can return something from `VectorDB::inputDB`? What makes you "unsure" about this? Do you get any errors? (In this code as posted you will probably get a lot of other errors)

Comment: Do you know how to read data from an `istream`? Do you know how to add elements to a `vector`? If not, you should probably break your problem down an start with those 2 things as separate questions. If you do, show your attempt.